# I'm trying to install WINE. But there are some problems!

Tags: wine, bug-reporting, winetricks

I want to install wine, but I can't. Firstly, I've written on Terminal: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
And after that I wrote this:
`wget -nc dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`
And then: `sudo apt-key add winehq.key`
Next stage this: `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy main'` And output was the following. Finally I have written
`sudo apt update` to update the package

```
>>>>>> uyivzola@BHZD:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
uyivzola@BHZD:~$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
File ‘winehq.key’ already there; not retrieving.


>>>>>> uyivzola@BHZD:~$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
File ‘winehq.key’ already there; not retrieving.


>>>>>> uyivzola@BHZD:~$ sudo apt-key add winehq.key
OK
>>>>>>uyivzola@BHZD:~$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main'
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease             
Hit:2 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Get:3 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/flameshot/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Err:2 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Get:5 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Err:3 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease [6,259 B]
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Err:5 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AC4E8D9CDCB0980D
Get:12 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages [84.0 kB]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/flameshot/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu focal Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:15 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy/main i386 Packages [84.1 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                            
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AC4E8D9CDCB0980D
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/flameshot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>>>> uyivzola@BHZD:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease             
Err:1 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/flameshot/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:6 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Err:2 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease          
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease         
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AC4E8D9CDCB0980D
Err:6 http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/flameshot/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AC4E8D9CDCB0980D
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/flameshot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Before any one can help you need to ask a clear question, You need to say what you did what you typed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Copying and pasting the errors in the question is very important and congratulations for doing that. However, you have to ask a question and describe the problem you are having.

Comment: I want to install wine, but I can't. 
Firstly, I've written on Terminal:
 sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
And after that I wrote this:
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
And then:
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
Next stage this:
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main'

And output was the following.
Finally I have written
sudo apt update
 to update the package

Comment: It seems as though you are using an old repository for WINE.  Try this one, in replace of the one you are using.  try this one: `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu'`

Comment: Please add the additional info to the body of the question.

Comment: Some folks do not know that a very good version of Wine is already in the Ubuntu repositories. No new source needed. No additional steps or commands needed. It's available in Ubuntu Software. Folks who want newer software should consider using an interim (6-month) release of Ubuntu instead of LTS (which will almost always have older software). Few folks should really need to add upstream Wine sources. You are welcome to add upstream sources (it's YOUR system), but only do so if you have the skills to troubleshoot basic apt conflicts like this.

Comment: Advice: Honestly, your sources seem a mess. You have two dead PPAs to remove. You have key problems with the Ubuntu repos. Take a few minutes and fix those basic problems before revisiting whether or not you want to install Wine using your current complex method.

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 This also does not work(
output was like that:
`Error: 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu' invalid`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Try to follow this tutorial: https://wine.htmlvalidator.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-20.04.html

Answer (score 0):

As the ppa is a 3rd party source, Ubuntu will not allow you to update while it is on the repo list.

I would recommend removing that ppa and installing Wine from a .deb package.

**Option One**

Fetch CPU details with this command: `lscpu`

Install Wine on a 64-bit system: `sudo apt-get install wine64

`

**Option Two**

Install Wine from Repo

Add I386 architecture: sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

Add repo: wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -

Add repo key: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv F987672F

Add relevant repo to list: sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'

Update package list: sudo apt-get update

Install Wine: sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Comment: What does this mean "As the ppa is a 3rd party source, Ubuntu will not allow you to update while it is on the repo list." I have 3rd party ppas and the software from them updates just fine.

Comment: The ppa http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease  is not canon.

Comment: Does that make sense? That is the PPA that is causing your problems.

Comment: No, your statement says that you can't update from 3rd party ppas. That's not correct.

Comment: You can't update from 3rd party ppas on an LTS version if they are not updated on a regular basis, my bad.